# Theme Creator Error (to install the apk exported)

Tags: sony

When I exported my theme, copy and paste in my SD card... When I go to install the apk, an error occurs while parsing the package... What I do? (I speak spanish)

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information, it is hard to tell. It can be various reasons.

1. You try to install a theme from a newer Android version. Your android version is unable to read the package.
2. You haven't signed your theme. If you don't sign your theme, Android will not install it.
3. When you transfer the file to your SD card, the file got corrupt. This can be a bad USB cable, a malfunctioning SD card or similar.

I hope I could help with that. Next time, please post errors and/or printscreens.